# Integrability of a continuous function over an open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following statement:

Let $I$ be a bounded open interval and let $f$ be a real function that is continuous on $I$. Then, $f$ is integrable on $I$

This statement is false, but I cannot understand why.  I thought that a continuous function on a bounded interval will be bounded, which seems to imply integrability.

Edit: Also, why is it then that $\lvert\int f(x)dx\rvert$ from $a$ to $b$, where $a,b$ are in the interval $I$, is strictly bounded?

Comment: A continuous function on a bounded _closed_ interval must be bounded.

Comment: Thank you! But why does this fail over an open interval?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1/x$ on $x\in (0,1)$. It is continuous and non integrable.

Comment: Ah! I see. But is the core reason why $1/x$ is not integrable over $(0,1)$ the fact that it is unbounded?

Comment: Are you working in the sense of Lebesgue, proper Riemann, or possibly-improper Riemann? (In any case, bounded "reasonable" functions are integrable, where "reasonable" has different meanings in each case).

Comment: Depending on the definition of integral you adopt, unbounded functions might or might not be integrable. But that one is *always* nonintegrable, because whatever definition you use, you must always have $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\, dx =\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} (\log 1 - \log \epsilon) = +\infty.$

Comment: @Ian I am working with the proper Riemann definition

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I see! thank you

Comment: OK. In that case it follows immediately from not being bounded. In the other two cases this is not true; for instance $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is integrable on $(0,1)$ in both of the other two cases.

Comment: Thank you Ian! Any input on the second part of my question?

Comment: For a bounded function this follows directly from the triangle inequality: $\left | \int_a^b f(x) dx \right | \leq \int_a^b |f(x)| dx \leq \int_a^b M dx = M(b-a)<\infty$.

Comment: Yes, but how can you be sure that $f$ is  bounded?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking "why is $F(x)=\left | \int_a^x f(y) dy \right |$ bounded for $x \in [a,b]$ if $f$ is properly Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$"? If so, then it follows from boundedness by the definition of proper Riemann integrability. Otherwise I don't think I understand the question.

Comment: Yes it is exactly what you have stated, and I think I understood now. Thank you.